# How to move the SKU on a woocommerce wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for some woocommerce help. I am building a website for video downloading. and the client is very specific where he wants things in the shop. on default, the SKU is on the bottom and the price is on the top.

[image]

I was able to find code to move the order for the price

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 45 );
```

And now I have it like this:

[image]

So, I was trying to find something similar for the SKU, I think it should look something like.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_SKU', 45 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_SKU', 10 );
```

I am super new to modifying woocommerce and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you editing the Woocommerce files directly ? The right way to do this would be to override the woocommerce template in your theme.. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files/

Comment: The SKU is displayed in template [single-product/meta.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.1/templates/single-product/meta.php) with other data like categories, tags…

So you should remove it [overriding this woocommerce template via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). then add it back in a hooked function where is convenient for you.

Comment: No, I am not editing the Woocommerce files directly. I am only adding code to the functions.php file inside my theme folder. once I get it working I read there is a plugin that I can use that will keep track of all the code I have even during a Woocomerce/theme update.

Answer (score 4):

The SKU is displayed in template [single-product/meta.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.1/templates/single-product/meta.php) with other data like categories, tags…

**Step 1** - You should remove it from this template.

This can be done [overriding this woocommerce template **via your theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php.

Once removed the SKU part, the template code will look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Meta
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

?>
<div class="product_meta">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
</div>
```

---

**Step 2** - The code that will reorder the price and put the Sku back in another location.

You will need to remove first your existing code (as it's included here).

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary_actions', 1 );
function custom_single_product_summary_actions(){

    // Reordering the price (done by you)
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 45 );

    // Put back the SKU:
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_custom_sku', 9 );
    function woocommerce_single_custom_sku(){
        global $product;

        if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) :
        ?>
            <p><span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span></p>
        <?php
        endif;
    }
}
```

*This function goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Thanks for helping LoicTheAztec, It seems that's the right direction. but I have 2 issues now. The SKU is at the top but there is also one at the bottom. Also because this is a variable product. You can have Digital download or ship DVD. I have a SKU for each one. when I switch to the other product the top one (the one I want to keep) Does not change. but the bottom one does. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Is there an answer how to do this with a variable product? I also have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use hook you can use this code :

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", function () {

    // move sku and category
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 15);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions file:
(You can change the second number "5" to change the postition)

```
// Reordering the SKU
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 5 );
```